# How to Upgrade Cisco AnyConnect?

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, firewall

So I am in the process of upgrading our Cisco AnyConnect client on our ASA from 3.1 to 4.4 for an upcoming ISE upgrade.

I've transferred the files to the ASA's flash, and we are ready to change the "anyconnect image XXXX" in the configuration.

Is there anything that will need to be done on user's computers?  It's mostly people in the IT department that use AnyConnect from home when needed.  Will the AnyConnect client on the user's computers simply pull the required files from the ASA?

Sorry if this is vague or not accurate, but I cannot seem to find the information I'm looking for, and this is my first time dabbling with this.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few strategies to deploying AnyConnect.   [The Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client Administrator Guide, Release 4.4](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/vpn_client/anyconnect/anyconnect44/administration/guide/b_AnyConnect_Administrator_Guide_4-4.html) describes them in detail including [client prerequisites and configurations](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/vpn_client/anyconnect/anyconnect44/administration/guide/b_AnyConnect_Administrator_Guide_4-4/deploy-anyconnect.html#d31825e306a1635).

> Deploying AnyConnect refers to installing, configuring, and upgrading
>   the AnyConnect client and its related files.
>
> The Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client can be deployed to remote
>   users by the following methods:
>
> - Pre-Deploy—New installations and upgrades are done either by the end    user, or by using an enterprise software management system
>     (SMS).
> - Web-Deploy—The AnyConnect package is loaded on the headend, which is    either an ASA or ISE server. When the user connects to an ASA or
>     to    ISE, AnyConnect is deployed to the client.
>
>   - For new installations, the user connects to a headend to download the    AnyConnect client. The client is either installed manually, or 
>       automatically (web-launch).
>   - Updates are done by AnyConnect running on a system where AnyConnect    is already installed, or by directing the user to the
>       ASA clientless    portal.

Answer (score 1):

1. Upload the 3.0 annyconnect.pkg file to the ASA (please note there are different files for Windows,Linux,Mac).
2. Under webvpn,set AnyConnect version 3 as priority 1 and version 2 as priority 2. See below:

   ```
   webvpn
    enable outside
    enable inside
    anyconnect image disk0:/anyconnect-win-3.1.02026-k9.pkg 1
    anyconnect image disk0:/anyconnect-win-2.5.0217-k9.pkg 2
   ```
3. Connect from client, it will be automatically upgraded to version 3.0.